# Could not copy from debug to bin in Blazor server app

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I have a Blazor server app working with it in Visual Studio 2022 version 17.3.376.3011 and Windows 11. All of a sudden I get these errors: Could not copy from debug to bin because IISEXPRESS.EXE is locking the file.The exact error message is:

> Could not copy "obj\Debug\net6.0\xxx.dll" to "bin\Debug\net6.0\xxx.dll".Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed. The file is locked by: "iisexpress.exe (4892)"

I have tried for solutions including:

1. Closing VS and try to delete obj and bin folders. Doesn't work since
   Bin folder can't be deleted because it is locked.
2. Exit IISExpress in
   system tray and then try to delete Bin (doesn't work still locked)
   and open VS to rebuild. Same problem.
3. Kill IISExpress in Task Manager. Won't work because of permission.
4. Clean solution and rebuild. Same error still.

The only thing that helped is to restart the computor and then it is released and I can continue working.

Is there someone with a fix for this that I'm grateful.

Comment: Try to find if the process is still running with Process Hacker freeware.

Comment: Check launchSettings.json file in Properties. Look for "leaveRunningOnClose" in IIS Express settings

Comment: @KonradP I don't have that property in my launchSettings. Should I add one and in that case what value should it have?

Comment: @Pettanord seems like there is some process hanging then

Comment: Just once I was hoping to try a new Microsoft technology and not end up with the same insanely frustrating errors I got literally twenty years ago.